# UITableView button and label is getting removed when i scroll up and down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView, each cell contains 3 buttons and 3 labels. When app loads first time, 2 buttons and 2 labels will be disabled. When 3rd button is clicked, all my 2 buttons and 2 labels have to show in the cell. So each cell has to apply the same scenario. So multiple cell may contain this. But now if same process if followed for any 3 or 4 cell, even for 1 cell and scrolling up and down.Then that 2 buttons and 2 labels are hidden.

Here my code how i tried :

```
var selectedIndexPaths = NSMutableSet()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsCell
if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            cell.OuterViewLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.Datalabel.isHidden = false
            cell.NameButnOutlet.isHidden = false
            cell.dropButnOutlet.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.OuterViewLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.Datalabel.isHidden = true
            cell.NameButnOutlet.isHidden = true
            cell.dropButnOutlet.isHidden = true
        }
}
```

Here when i press any cell BUTTON to show my 2 button and 2 label to show  that cell:

```
func showHidenoutlets() {    
 cell.OuterViewLabel.isHidden = false
 cell.Datalabel.isHidden = false
 cell.NameButnOutlet.isHidden = false
 cell.dropButnOutlet.isHidden = false
}
```

When I scroll up and down, already showing cell button, label and all again hiding. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` is called each time the cell moves out of the scrollView and comes back..

Comment: @Skywalker so what should i needs to do, to handle this

Comment: one way to handle it is create a `struct` or a `class` and add a property `selected` and update it when click on cell and read that from  `cellForRowAt ` method.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni  any example code would be helpfull

Comment: If you give it a try on google you will find an example for it

Comment: How do you distinguish selectedIndexPaths? Where do you update that Set?

Comment: @Skywalker  i just did that much only..i din set i think..after that any thing needs to set ?

Comment: Then how will that condition (`selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)`) ever be true?

Comment: please let me wr i needs to set it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `indexPath` to `selectedIndexPaths` when button is clicked.

```
var selectedIndexPaths = NSMutableSet()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsCell
    let notClicked = !selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
    cell.OuterViewLabel.isHidden = notClicked
    cell.Datalabel.isHidden = notClicked
    cell.NameButnOutlet.isHidden = notClicked
    cell.dropButnOutlet.isHidden = notClicked
}

func showHidenoutlets(cell: DetailsCell, indexPath: IndexPath, add: Bool = true) {
    if add {
        selectedIndexPaths.add(indexPath)
    }
    cell.OuterViewLabel.isHidden = !add
    cell.Datalabel.isHidden = !add
    cell.NameButnOutlet.isHidden = !add
    cell.dropButnOutlet.isHidden = !add
}
```

[This](https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1) might help you understand work flow. `showHidenoutlets` can be delegate method to call on controller.

Comment: if i call `showHidenoutlets` this to my button action then it throws the error of `Use of undeclared type 'DetailsCell'`

Comment: You need to call it in button action, you cannot assign it to button action.

Comment: yes, but how can i call it...i tried in button action still i am getting 'DetailsCell' error

Comment: I have added a link to a tutorial. Seems like you have bigger problems than this.